# filter based on variable, if no value in variable apply NO filters

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Based on a filter I would like to apply that to what to filter.

For example if I have a variable called p_filter that could have the values 'A' or 'B' I would like to filter specific where clauses based on that.

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE
id NOT IN (select id from t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+) ) --only apply this filter if p_filter = 'A'
AND id NOT IN (select id from t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.id(+) )  --only apply this filter if p_filter = 'B'
```

If the variable though is null, I would like for it to apply NO filters. I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE
CASE WHEN :p_filter != 'A' THEN 1 WHEN id NOT IN (select id from t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+) ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
AND CASE WHEN :p_filter != 'B' THEN 1 WHEN  id NOT IN (select id from t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.id(+) ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1;
```

UPDATE: I am so stupid, I meant if null apply no filters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
WHERE
   --only apply this filter if p_filter = 'A'
   p_filter = 'A' 
   AND
   id NOT IN (select id from t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+) ) 

   OR

   --only apply this filter if p_filter = 'B'
   p_filter = 'B' 
   AND
   id NOT IN (select id from t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.id(+) )  

   OR

   -- If the variable though is null, I would like for it to apply both filters
   p_filter IS NULL
   AND
   id NOT IN (select id from t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+) ) 
   AND
   id NOT IN (select id from t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.id(+) )
```

**---- EDIT ---------**

> I am so sorry, I am stupid, I meant to say if null apply NO filters! –
>   user2924127

In that case just remove the last condition, and add `OR p_filter IS NULL`:

```
WHERE
   --only apply this filter if p_filter = 'A'
   p_filter = 'A' 
   AND
   id NOT IN (select id from t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+) ) 

   OR

   --only apply this filter if p_filter = 'B'
   p_filter = 'B' 
   AND
   id NOT IN (select id from t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.id(+) )  

   -- I am so sorry, I am stupid, I meant to say if null apply NO filters!
   OR
   p_filter IS NULL
```

Comment: I am so sorry, I am stupid, I meant to say if null apply NO filters!

Answer (score 1):

To do this "OR" the negative of your condition like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE 
(:p_filter IS NULL OR :p_filter!='A' OR id NOT IN (select id from t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+) ))
AND (:p_filter IS NULL OR :p_filter!='B' OR id NOT IN (select id from t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.id(+) ))
```

Comment: I am so sorry, I am stupid, I meant to say if null apply NO filters!

Comment: I adjusted the query above to make null do neither filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM t1
 WHERE ( 
         (p_filter = 'A' and id NOT IN (select id from t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id(+) )) 
          or 
         (p_filter = 'B' and id NOT IN (select id from t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.id(+) ))
          or 
         (p_filter is null)
       )
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged.